# Format number in android EditText on realtime editing #,###

Tags: java, android

I am working on Android project. 
I need to format number in EditText in realtime editing

for example:

- when I type: 1234 it should be 1,234
- when I type: 0123 it should be 0,123

What I have now it's not working :/, I set my EditText to only numeric input already.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    try {

                        //String str = s.toString();

                        //String str = String.format("%,d", s.toString()
                        //        .replaceAll(",", ""));
                        editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                        String str = s.toString().replaceAll(",", "");
                        String edit = "";
                        if(str.length()==2)
                        {
                            int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
                            String firstChar = str.substring(0, 1);
                            String secondChar = str.substring(1, str.length()-1);
                            edit = firstChar+ "," +secondChar;  
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            edit = str;
                        }
                        editText.setSelection(edit.length());
                        editText.setText(edit);
                        editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                public String doubleToStringNoDecimal(double d) {
                    DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);;
                    formatter .applyPattern("#,###");
                    return formatter.format(d);
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence c, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
//                  String str = editText.getText().toString(); 
//                  len = str.length();
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { 
//                  String str = editText.getText().toString();

                }


            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this one with your code:

```
String num = "1234567";
num = new StringBuilder(num).reverse().toString().replaceAll("(\\d{3})", "$1,");
num = new StringBuilder(num).reverse().toString().replaceAll("^,|,$", "");
System.out.println(num);
```

Output:

```
1,234,567
```